# Legally displaying another programs icon

Tags: copyright, advertisements

I'm making an app which controls other applications. I am displaying different program icons to identify which application the user is controlling.

I never save the icons or distribute them. The app finds the image from the users computer only when the program is running.

Are there any legal implications here? If I were to advertise my app by posting screenshots which display another programs icon, does that infringe upon any copyrights?

I was looking at [this question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1987/legal-stance-on-using-application-icons-within-our-product) but I wasn't really sure if that answers my question or not. I know next to nothing about legal matters.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the answer on your linked question from [User Experience](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1987/legal-stance-on-using-application-icons-within-our-product) is correct, your questions are basically identical to each other.

Generally, logo's are used to identify a product. Many software organizations actually encourage you to use them to identify their items. They will generally come with guidelines that dictate how they can be used: Here are [Microsoft's guidelines as an example](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/legal/intellectualproperty/trademarks/usage/default.aspx).

If you're querying the Windows APIs to find the images, you should just about be fine. You're not necessarily distributing them, and you're using it to identify a product that is not yours.